# Disable a button in c# under a condition

Tags: c#, arrays, button, arraylist, listbox

So, I'm having this array that adds elements one by one pressing a button, and it adds elements  with this:
`arreglo.Add(textBox1.Text.ToString());`

I just want to limit the amount of elements it can add to the array, to 10. It can have up to ten elements, no more. How do i do that?

If it helps, these are parts of my code I think it can help:

```
ArrayList arreglo;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        arreglo = new ArrayList();
    }
```

and

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Agregar
        arreglo.Add(textBox1.Text.ToString());
        /*if (arreglo.Count > 10)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("No more than ten elements");
        }*/
        this.textBox1.Clear();
        this.textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

And btw, i also need to do some calculations with that array, but i already have that covered.

Comment: u wish to disable a button or limit array length?

Comment: @mihirj I want to disable a button once the limit of the array is hit.

Comment: Please see if below answer works for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply solve this as:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Agregar
        arreglo.Add(textBox1.Text.ToString());
        if (arreglo.Count > 10)
        {
            button5.Enabled = false;
        }
        this.textBox1.Clear();
        this.textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: If this has solved your problem, can u please mark this as answer?

Comment: Actually, I used both questions as an answer. But this helped me the most, so this will be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to change array capacity while, in this case, array is capable from 0 up to 9 (10 elements)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                list.Capacity = 9;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { button5.Enabled = false; }
            list.Add("teststring");
        }
        list = list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check after adding how many elements your array have and set the `Button` enabled property to false - it will disable button.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   arreglo.Add(textBox1.Text.ToString());
   this.textBox1.Focus();       
   this.textBox1.Clear();   

   if (arreglo.Count >= 10)
   {
       button5.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i already have the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why `ArrayList`? what is your purpose?

```
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arreglo.Count < 10)
        {
            arreglo.Add(textBox1.Text);
            this.textBox1.Clear();
            this.textBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
            button10.Enable = false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but i have it covered. Thanks again!

Comment: welcome, you can __upvote__ the answer if you think that's useful for you and you can accept as __answer__ if that answer is the best for you ..Welcome in stackoveflow `:D`